# How to display B&W pixel images on a TI-84 graphic calculator (Non-CE version)

Tags: image, ti-basic

I've seen images online of people able to display black & white pixel images on their TI brand graphing  calculators:
[image]

I've tried googling around but I can only find instructions for color images for the TI-84 Plus CE calculator, and nothing for the older black and white screened calculators (Ex TI-84 plus which is what I have).

**How do I display a black and white image on an older non-color TI graphing calculator?**

Are there ways to import and display an image? Or do you draw it using individual points for each pixel? (I've seen instructions for making images using the graphing function, but I'm not sure if these images were created this way). Or is there a different way to do it?

Comment: You can also display 8 level greyscale pictures. [See here](https://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/429/42907.html)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need your calculator, the standard a to mini b usb cable, a Windows or Mac computer, TI Connect Software, and an editing software such as photoshop. 
Open your picture in your editing software. Desaturate the image, resize the image to 192 by 128, bring up the contrast to maximum, and save the image.
Go to this website or any website to pixelate the image.
https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/8bit-picture.php
Go to adjustment levels on your editing software to make the blacks truly black and the whites truly white.
Copy your image and open TI Connect. Plug in your calculator and turn it on. Paste your picture and save it. Press the Send Picture button, remember the file name you choose. 
To open the picture make sure your drawing is clear and your axes are off, go to draw, choose RacallPic in the STO menu, enter the number of the file name you saved it on and you have your picture. Hope this helps.